# Spring security hierarchical role system and ant matchers not working as expected

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, ant, authorization

I am trying to secure parts of my web application by using ant matchers and have also configured hierarchical roles. Below is my security configuration.

Role Hierarchy:

```
private SecurityExpressionHandler<FilterInvocation> webExpressionHandler() {
    DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
    defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy());
    return defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler;
}


@Bean
public RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy(){
    RoleHierarchyImpl hierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    hierarchy.setHierarchy("SUPER_ADMIN > ADMIN ADMIN > PATIENT");
    return hierarchy;
}
```

User & Roles:

```
@Autowired
public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("rakesh").password("rakesh").roles("PATIENT");
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("root").password("root").roles("ADMIN");
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("notroot").password("notroot").roles("SUPER_ADMIN");
}
```

Request Authorization:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/web/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/web/login")
            .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/web/patient/home")
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .expressionHandler(webExpressionHandler())
            .antMatchers("/web/patient/add*").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/web/patient/home").access("hasRole('PATIENT')")  // home URL
            .antMatchers("/allpatients").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/web/**").permitAll()
            .and()
        .httpBasic()
            .realmName(env.getRequiredProperty("basicauthentication.realm"))
            .authenticationEntryPoint(getBasicAuthEntryPoint())
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/web/accessdenied")
            .and()
        .csrf().disable();
}
```

With the above setup none of the user is able to login, they are returned to the login page. If I comment out the `home URL` line in authorizeRequest, it works. Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Using the same url for loginPage and loginProcessingUrl looks extrange to me.
I suggest you to change one of them, maybe like this:

```
.formLogin()
            .loginPage("/web/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/web/performLogin")
```